# How to add a border radius invertedly?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to achieve this:
[image]

But when  `border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0` I get this: [image]

Comment: That is not directly possible using border-radius. You could place a white element with a border-radius over the red rectangle ... If you need transparency of that part as well, then look into using _masks_.

Comment: CSS/HTML supports masking?

Comment: You can aslo do this pseudo css3

Answer (score 2):

Border-radius alone doesn't answer this but you can do it like this:

Overflow hidden on an outer box with circle corners:
https://codepen.io/sergejmueller/pen/fJEml

```
border-radius: 50%;
```

You can also use radial gradients:
http://lea.verou.me/2011/03/beveled-corners-negative-border-radius-with-css3-gradients/

```
background-image:
radial-gradient(circle at 0 0, rgba(204,0,0,0) 14px, #c00 15px),
radial-gradient(circle at 100% 0, rgba(204,0,0,0) 14px, #c00 15px),
radial-gradient(circle at 100% 100%, rgba(204,0,0,0) 14px, #c00     15px),
radial-gradient(circle at 0 100%, rgba(204,0,0,0) 14px, #c00 15px);
```

Also mask image for a modern solution:

```
-webkit-mask-image: radial-gradient(circle 10px at 0 0, transparent 0, transparent 20px, black 21px);
```

Comment: I think that using ::before would be better. This way you are creating unnecessary HTML markup.

Comment: It's still the same idea though. ::before and ::after are just pseudo elements

Comment: Yeah! Its the same idea indeed! +1 for that. But creating a habit of an optimized code is a good start to everyone. In a larger project, it may significantly improve his project just by using good habits such as this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do using this `:before`css selector:

```css
.box{
  background:red;
  width:50px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius:3px;
  position:relative;
  margin-top:30px;
}
.box:before{
  content:"";
  width:50px;
  height:30px;
  border-radius:100%;
  background:#fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: -17px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```